# Maven does not run @BeforeEach Methods while running

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin, junit5

i have a test Class lets call it `TestSomething`, and a Test Object lets call this one `SomeObject`.

Now i need this Object in every Single Test new this means that i have in my Code a `@BeforeEach` that loads this Object in a Field:

```
import me.test.SomeObject;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class TestSomething {
    private SomeObject someObject;

    @BeforeEach
    public void load() {
        someObject = new SomeObject();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        boolean result = someObject.checkForSomething();
        Assertions.assertEquals(true, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        boolean result = someObject.checkForSomethingElse();
        Assertions.assertEquals(false, result);
    }
```

pom.xml from the Test Module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <parent>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <groupId>me.test</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


  <properties>
    <projectVersion>1.0.0</projectVersion>
    <maven.deploy.skip>false</maven.deploy.skip>
  </properties>


  <artifactId>Tests</artifactId>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>me.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>project</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

not sure if it is relevant, but the Object `SomeObject` is in a separate Module, and the Test Module has a Dependency on that Module with Scope `test`. (i also tried `provided` and `compile`)

So now if i Run this Tests in InteliJ they Work just Fine. but now if i try to Build my Project the Tests Fail, with NullPointerExceptions because `someObject` is `null`.

Now the Test work of i call the Method `load()` in every Test, but that is not exactly what i want.

Comment: Show your maven configuration. Maybe, you didn't configure the maven-surefire-plugin as it should. Please show also your imports in the test class.

Comment: Added every thing you said, but did not spesificly configure the surefile plugin

Comment: So the problem is there. Check out that : https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven

Comment: The surefire plugin will still not pickup the `@BeforeEach` annotated methods when you forget to add the `junit-jupiter-engine` artifact as a dependency. IDE's are content when you have the `junit-jupiter-api` artifact added, but the surefire plugin will revert back to a junit3 runner when you don't specify the engine also. Surefire will still run your tests, even if the `@Test` annotation is from the `org.junit.jupiter.api` package. However, the `@BeforeEach` (and  `@AfterEach` etc.) annotated methods will not be executed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By default Maven will not run the test with the Jupiter engine as

> In order to have Maven Surefire run any tests at all, a TestEngine
> implementation must be added to the runtime classpath.

And this is not present by default.
So to enable it you have to configure the maven-surefire-plugin that runs the unit tests as documented in the [Jupiter documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven) :

UPDATE (28.10.2020):

**Since version 2.22.0**, you only have to specify a test dependency on the desired junit engine. Failing to do so, will also result in the behavior described in the question.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Keeping the original answer as a reference, **before version 2.22.0** the solution was:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

---

Whatever the issue is not necessarily easy to spot because Maven uses a runner that is able to run the Jupiter tests but didn't manage to execute the hook methods...

As a hint : to know whether the JUnit 5 runner is launched you can execute the tests with the verbose flag such as : `mvn test -X`.
If the Jupiter runner is used, you should find lines that look like :

> [DEBUG] Surefire report directory: ...\target\surefire-reports
>
> [DEBUG] Using configured provider
> org.junit.platform.surefire.provider.JUnitPlatformProvider

Comment: that fixed the problem thanks :D I only needed to add that to the pom of my test Module.

Comment: You are very welcome :)  JUnit 5 is not the standard yet. So maven doesn't include it by default. But in few years, it should change I hope ! I updated the answer. This may help.

Comment: Time flies by... Maven Surefire 2.22.0 now supports JUnit 5 out of the box.

Comment: Just wanted to add that if you use Spring Boot you must exclude the junit-vintage-engine library from the spring-boot-starter-test dependency. Because we were using some junit 4 annotations in our test somehow manve ran the tests with the junit4 runner instead of junit 5. After excluding the dependency and refactoring all junit4 annotations to junit5 it worked!

Comment: As @MarcPhilipp already mentioned, version 2.22.0 supports JUnit without the need of junit-platform-surefire-provider. You still have to include test dependencies to the correct test engine. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

The first you need to do is to add a dependency like this:

```
<dependencies>
    [...]
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    [...]
</dependencies>
```

The next thing is to use the most recent version of [maven-surefire-plugin/maven-failsafe-plugin like this](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>some test to exclude here</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Starting with version 2.22.2 surefire supports JUnit 5...

Update:

- Use most recent version of maven-surefire/failsafe-plugin

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue. My SpringBoot app was already using the junit-jupiter-engine, but with an older surefire plugin. Forcing it to v2.22.2 did the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

maven-surefire-plugin by default takes all test classes which have the pattern *Test.java, in your case you should rename the class SomethingTest and it should be OK

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Comment: well it runs the test but they just Fail, see: https://hastebin.com/makemirifu.css